# Convert bytes object to string object in python

Tags: python

python code

```
#!python3

import sys
import os.path
import codecs

if not os.path.exists(sys.argv[1]):
    print("File does not exist: " + sys.argv[1])
    sys.exit(1)
file_name = sys.argv[1]

with codecs.open(file_name, 'rb', errors='ignore') as file:
    file_contents = file.readlines()

for line_content in file_contents:
    print(type(line_content))
    line_content = codecs.decode(line_content)
    print(line_content)
    print(type(line_content))
```

File content : Log.txt

```
b'\x03\x00\x00\x00\xc3\x8a\xc3\xacRb\x00\x00\x00\x00042284899:ATBADSFASF:DSF456582:US\r\n1'
```

Output:

```
python3 file_convert.py Log.txt                                                                                                                                               ✔  19:08:22 
<class 'bytes'>
b'\x03\x00\x00\x00\xc3\x8a\xc3\xacRb\x00\x00\x00\x00042284899:ATBADSFASF:DSF456582:US\r\n1'
<class 'str'>
```

I tried all the below methods

```
line_content = line_content.decode('UTF-8')
line_content = line_content.decode()
line_content = codecs.decode(line_content, 'UTF-8')
```

Is there any other way to handle this? 
The line_content variable still holds the byte data and only the type changes to str which is kind off confusing.

Comment: The `line_content` variable doesn't hold the byte data, it holds the ASCII representation of the byte data that was in your file.  If you `print(repr(line_content))` you'll see another level of quotes around it because it's a `str`, and if you `print(line_content)` before calling `decode()` on it you'll see that it's all ASCII bytes (e.g. there are no null bytes in it).

Comment: @Samwise because the file was opened in binary mode with the `'b'` flag, it really does return bytes and not a string when you read it.  ASCII is not involved.

Comment: Log.txt is literally the string you post? Then somebody saved what looks like python `Bytes` objects to the file. Maybe the answer is to fix what wrote that file.

Comment: It returns a `bytes` object, but if the file is ASCII, it's still ASCII data.  That is to say, `"\x00"` is not `0`, it's `92 120 48 48`.  I'm not clear on what OP is *trying* to get -- do they want to get the actual bytes represented by that string, such that `\x00` becomes `0`?  If so, `ast.literal_eval` might be the easiest way.

Comment: @Samwise if you look at *all* the bytes it's clear its not ASCII.  In fact it looks to me like intermixed binary data and text, and turning the whole thing into text will be nearly impossible unless you have a detailed file specification.

Comment: @Samwise sorry, I take it back.  I get what you're saying now after re-reading the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data in `Log.txt` is the string representation of a python `Bytes` object. That is odd but we can deal with it. Since its a `Bytes` literal, evaluate it, which converts it to a real python `Bytes` object. Now there is still a question of what its encoding is.

I don't see any advantage to using `codecs.open`. That's a way to read unicode files in python 2.7, not usually needed in python 3. Guessing UTF-8, your code would be

```
#!python3

import sys
import os
import ast

if not os.path.exists(sys.argv[1]):
    print("File does not exist: " + sys.argv[1])
    sys.exit(1)
file_name = sys.argv[1]

with open(file_name) as file:
    file_contents = file.readlines()

for line_content in file_contents:
    print(type(line_content))
    line_content = ast.literal_eval(line_content).decode("utf-8")
    print(line_content)
    print(type(line_content))
```

Comment: This solution worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I think it's a list not a string. Whenever you look at byte-string started with `\` (reverse backslash), it's potentially a list

try this

```
decoded_line_content = list(line_content)
```